# Image.uri not displaying images of the links in my Rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my final year project on Rails. I got the idea from an IEEE paper. It is called "News recommendation using Twitter" where it fetches the hashtag keywords from the user's twitter timeline and gives latest news articles on a personalized index page based on those keywords.

I am almost done with it. But I am facing problem in displaying the images of those fetched articles. Its fetching the link of that article but not the image of that link. Please check the [`app/views/tweets/index.html.erb`](https://github.com/YunoLevi/Toradora) on Github and let me know why it isn't fetching the images along. Thank You.

Current index page:

[image]

Comment: Seems like there is no issue with your code. The only thing is google search returning image url or not. try put debugger in code and see if you are getting images or not.